# Replace multiple occurences of a string in cells

Tags: regex, libreoffice, find-and-replace

Is it possible to replace a certain string that can occur multiple times in a single cell, but also in multiple cells? I'd like to prefix the first character `/` with another string `::` in comma separated value. Some examples

```
----------------       --------------------
| /x           |       | ::x              |
----------------       --------------------
| /x,/yy,/z/zz |       | ::x,::yy,::z/zz  |
----------------       --------------------
| x/x,/y/y     |       | x/x,::y/y        |
----------------       --------------------
| x/,          |  ===> | x/,              |   
----------------       --------------------
| /x/,,        |       | ::x/,,           |   
----------------       --------------------
| //           |       | ::/              |
----------------       --------------------
| /,,/         |       | ::,,::           |
----------------       --------------------
|              |       |                  |
----------------       --------------------
```

That is, replace every prefix slash in a comma seperated list of values.

Is that possible with with *Find and Replace* and regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following regex: `(^|,)/` and replace with `$1::`.

- Check Regular expression

**Explanation:**

```
(^|,)       # group 1, beginning of line or a comma
/           # a slash
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]